# Xamarin zxing don't ask allow permission camera on IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, zxing

I make simple xamarin project.

Then add NugetPackage Zxing.Net.Mobile.Forms 2.2.9 PCL,Android,IOS projects.

I add this code in AppDelegats.cs

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();

        NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"];
        LoadApplication(new App { OSVersion = "iOS Version " + "2.0" });

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Then add a Camera Permission in info.plist file like this.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Scan using the camera.</string>
```

And i Test with IOS Simulator.
But It don't ask me to permit use camera.

And Zxing ScanPage showed, But it just graycolor view.

So, First I don't know why don't appear to ask permit Camera with dialog.
Second, IOS simulator Don't support camera?

Android emulator is at least able to checking work camera.

Please teach me if you know. Thank you.

Comment: Yes ,you are right. Camera is only available on real device.

Comment: Cole Xia // Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try in Visual Studio menu bar `Build` ➤ `Rebuild Solution`

Reopen Visual Studio and Run your app again